# How to use SimpleElastix through SimpleITK

Tags: elastix

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kp6vN.png)
I noticed that SimpleElastix is no longer maintained and integrated into SimpleITK. the link is "https://github.com/SuperElastix/SimpleElastix".

what does that mean to use SimpleElastix through SimpleITK by enabling the CMake option 'SimpleITK_USE_ELASTIX'.

Could anyone tell me something about this?

Answer (score 0):

According to
https://simpleitk.readthedocs.io/en/master/building.html

you give the option as follows:

```
cmake ../SimpleITK/SuperBuild -DSimpleITK_USE_ELASTIX=ON
```

or via some cmake-GUI (never used it myself, though)

It compiled just fine and my previous code emplyoing the python wrapper runs as before. I stumbled on the same issue and your question popped up when searching for the solution  ;)

Answer (score 0):

The SimpleElastix source code is now in the SimpleITK code base.  However the python packages of SimpleITK are not compiled with SimpleElastix enabled.  To get SimpleElastix you're going to have to compile the source code yourself.

Basically you should be able to compile it as follows:

```
cmake ../SimpleITK/SuperBuild -DSimpleITK_USE_ELASTIX=ON
cmake --build . --config Release
```

This assumes you have cmake, python and a C++ compiler installed.